# Model class c# key column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model

What is means the Column tag with the Key tag. Thank you

```
public class Order
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 1)]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Key,Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ProductID{ get; set; }
    public virtual Order order{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep but I didn't found the answer

Comment: Why to have 2 primary keys here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you are defining a composite primary key and using the `Column` attribute you can define the order of your primary keys. For example when you need to search an specific `Order` using the `Find` method, you need to pass as parameters the keys in the same order that you define in your entity:

```
var order= context.Orders.Find(orderId, productId);
```

For more info you can go to this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Composite).

Answer (score 0):

it's a composite primary key for Order table.